# Basic downgrade of component in angular 2 with parameter gets Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, systemjs

[image]For some reason when I downgrade a simple component with 1 input parameter, I get this message:

---

> (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for MyLabelComponent: (?).

---

the same component without any paramter will work just fine. What is wrong? Did I missed something? I did evertyhing by the angular.io tutorial about downgrade angular 2 component to work in angular 1 app.

**my-label.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-label',
  templateUrl: './my-label.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-label.component.css']
})
export class MyLabelComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() text: string;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**my-label.component.html**

```
<div class="my-label">{{text}}</div>
```

**my-label.component.css**

```
.my-label {  color: red;  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MyLabelComponent } from './my-label/my-label.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyLabelComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyLabelComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}


import * as _angular_ from 'angular';

declare global {
  const angular: typeof _angular_;
}


import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

angular.module('myModule')
  .directive('myLabel', downgradeComponent({component: MyLabelComponent, inputs: ['text']}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory);
```